# wordpress add a new page or update cause The response is not a valid JSON response because of simple plugin

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am trying to make a plugin in WordPress. The plugin is working fine but when someone adds a new page or updates a page it shows an error message saying:

```
The response is not a valid JSON response.
```

I checked up the plugin code and found out it was doing that because of html part code in the file. I tried to find a fix for it but had no luck so far.

Here is the PHP plugin file, can you tell me what is wrong

```
<?php
/*
 * Plugin Name: test
 */
 

function testfunc () {

?>

<div class="testcl">test</div>

<?php
}
add_shortcode('test','testfunc');
?>
```

Comment: Try delaying your `add_shortcode` call until after `init` has fired: https://3v4l.org/OZskt

Comment: still the same even tried in new installer for wordpress it's look like the plugins access everywhere and it cause the bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to buffer the output template when you create a shortcode. try this code :

```
<?php
/*
 * Plugin Name: test
 */
 

function testfunc () {
ob_start();
?>

<div class="testcl">test</div>

<?php
return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('test','testfunc');
?>
```

Comment: ok thanks that fixed it i was just trying this way
`<?php
/*
 * Plugin Name: test
 */
 $uri = parse_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH );
//echo $request_uri;

if (strpos($uri,'testpage') !== false) {
    echo 'its testpage';
} else {
    echo 'wrong page';
    return;
}

function testfunc () {

?>

<div class="testcl">test</div>

<?php

add_shortcode('test','testfunc');
}`
it also worked